# Does it exist JS template engine with functions (objects) support?

Tags: javascript, template-engine

does it exist JS template engine with functions (objects) support? Without helpers and other crutches (**no framework!** angular, etc).

For examle, I need something like this on JS:

```
var user = new User();
```

And In HTML template

```
<div>
    ...    
    Hello, {{ user.name() }}
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Handlebars, Mustache, AngularJS, EJS, JS Templates, etc.

Comment: Angular - framework. I need only template engine. Handlebars don't support functions in simple use, only via helpers.

Comment: Maybe try grips? Never used it, but it's made by Kyle Simpson, so you know it is quality and well thought out. https://github.com/getify/grips

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS template strings:

```js
const user = {
    name: "Alex",
    getName () {
      return this.name;
    } 
};

console.log(`Hello, ${user.getName()}`);
```

Comment: OP wants to be able to interpolate JavaScript from HTML

Comment: @mhodges, this is the only way to do it without frameworks / template engines

Comment: OP said templating engines are fine, just not full-blown frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

The wording of your question is quite difficult to comprehend; however, I believe this may be what you are looking for.

You can use a span to fill in the text via JS:

```
<script>
    function fillName() {
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = user.name;
    }
</script>

<div>
    Hello, <span id="name"></span>
</div>
```